# Failed to load Android and TWRP recovery after flashing twrp recovery image

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, twrp, lenovo

The device is Lenovo Tab 2 A8-50LC
I flashed the device with a (apparently) TWRP recovery image.

```
./fastboot flash  recovery recovery.img 
target reported max download size of 134217728 bytes
sending 'recovery' (10454 KB)...
OKAY [  0.904s]
writing 'recovery'...

OKAY [  0.306s]
finished. total time: 1.209s
```

After that:

```
./fastboot reboot
rebooting...

finished. total time: 0.052s
```

But the device can not load TWRP or Android and restarts consequently.
No power-off, volume-up or down or any combinations work here. Nothing works:

```
./adb reboot recovery
error: no devices found

./fastboot devices

./adb reboot bootloader
error: no devices found
```

The only way is to disconnect the battery from the board.
Any suggestions highly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: where did you get the twrp image?

Comment: You can find it over here: https://twrp.me/app/

Comment: I cant find it under https://twrp.me/Devices/Lenovo/, nor when searching for A8-50. A direct link would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `adb reboot recovery` at the earliest time I see Team Win is starting up. That works and give me the fastboot mode.
Then I flashed another recovery image.